# Angular $compile works ... then doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I have a large and complex application which allows the user to compose their own dashboard view of items consisting of Angular directives. I'm loading the directives' HTML, $compile'ing it, and adding it to the view. The user can define numerous views and can change between them at will.

All this works fine for the first time a particular view (with its user defined directives) is rendered. Go to a different view, and all is good. However, coming back to a view that's already been rendered and nothing is being $compile'd for that view.

The directives' are being removed in the DOM between views, and I can confirm their removal works.

Unfortunately it's not practical to isolate the code that renders the view to paste it here as there's so much going on between the views and the numerous different services required to compose the view.

So basically ... has anybody encountered this before, where repeated $compile'ing of the same directive works and then fails?

Comment: Sometimes one line of code is worth more than 1000 words

Comment: Why are you re-compiling when they come back - it's already compiled? I believe the result is cached in `$cacheProvider` anyway, so that may be where it is going wrong.

Comment: There is no way to give a definitive answer unless you give something to work on. Probably, you would be using ng-bind-html to display html and it doesn't support two-way binding. At least, that is how I have faced a similar issue.

Comment: @Rhumborl I'm suspecting it may well be a cache issue, based on nothing more than it's pretty much the only avenue I've not explored at the moment.

Comment: @damiano The code that does the $compile itself probably isn't the issue. It works - the first time it's used for a particular directive. Beyond that, there's so much DOM manipulation going on and interaction with numerous other services between the initial and subsequent $compile that it would be impossible to follow the lifespan of one of the affected directives just by pasting a snippet of code here.

Comment: I managed to resolve an identical issue by using `$rootScope` when creating a new scope for compilation, instead of just using the scope injected into my directive i.e. `$scope.$root.$new(true)` (which is then modified with my scope data and passed into the generated compile function)